# Regex pattern for this rtmp://username:password@x.x.x.x:port/application/streamname for JAVA

Tags: java, regex

Can someone help with this regex pattern: rtmp://username:password@x.x.x.x:port/application/streamname

Where :

- Group 1 is the host: x.x.x.x
- Group 2 is the port
- Group 3 is the application
- Group 4 is the streamname

I've already tried the following pattern, but it doesn't seem to capture the groups as I expect it to:

```
^rtmp://.*?:?.*?[@?]([^/:]+)(:(\\d+))*:?.*/([^/]+)(/(.*))*$
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: I have tried this so far:   ^rtmp://.*?:?.*?[@?]([^/:]+)(:(\\d+))*:?.*/([^/]+)(/(.*))*$

Comment: Not getting the groups right

Comment: I would expect your previous attempt to fail with some sort of syntax error as your slashes (`/`) are not escaped properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this regex :

```
rtmp.*?@(.*?):(\d+)\/(\w+)\/(\w+)
```

**Demo :**
[Here](https://regex101.com/r/Der6wv/2)

Answer (score 2):

As always, you should avoid using regular expressions if you can rely on a parser specific to the data you're parsing.

In your case you're parsing an URI, so I suggest you rely on the `java.net.URI` class :

```
URI uri = new URI("rtmp://username:password@x.x.x.x:port/application/streamname");
uri.getHost(); // your desired hostname
uri.getPort(); // your desired port
uri.getPath().split('/')[1]; // your desired application
uri.getPath().split('/')[2]; // your desired streamname
```

You can [try it here](https://ideone.com/8mA6rf).